# How to do flipside function in python 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day fellow programmers!

This is the instructions I got for my python class and I am struggling so hard to make the input appear as I'd like.

*flipside(s) takes a string s and returns a string whose first half is s's second half and the second half is the first. if the length is odd, the first half of the input string should have one fewer character than the second half. For example, the string carpet would have the output petcar. The input carpets would have the output petscar.*

This is my current code:

```
def flipside():

    print("This program will return second half as first half of what you write.")
    s = input("Type in any word: ")

    newWord = len(s)%2
    print("DEBUG: ",newWord)

    if newWord == 1:
        print("DEBUG: ODD")
        print (s[3:]+s[:4])
    else:
        print("DEBUG: EVEN")
        print(s[4:]+s[:4])
```

I am really confused of what I should type inside the brackets to slice up the words properly. I've searched around using google to find solution for this function, and none work.

Could any experienced Python programmer explain to me what I've done wrong with my code? I'd like to learn.

I am using python 3.0

Comment: I'm writing to you because you're new to SO. The main thing I notice about this question is that you haven't said what you want to achieve. (And then there's the fact that some people on SO will object to being asked to solve problems for students.)

Comment: Bill Bell, thanks for letting me know. I am completely new to SO and was recommended by my classmates to seek out help there if there are anything I don't understand. I apologize for not saying what I want to achieve. I'll edit my main post.

Comment: Read the intro tour; that will cover a lot of the new-chum problems.  I still refer to it about once a month.

Comment: @Kevin: No worries! Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of Python programming, just of finding the division point.  Whatever you find, your new string will be of the second form you give:

```
s[div_pt:] + s[:div_pt]
```

The "ODD" case you give repeats the 4th letter.

Integer division should solve your problem for you:

```
div_pt = len(s) // 2
```

Can you slip those into your program and see what you get?  Try a couple of different examples, such as "carpet" and "ashtray".

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not very good at math, so I learn everyday and whenever I program! Works perfectly as far as I can understand the function. Thanks for widening my knowledge with the " // ". Have a great day!

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Remember to up-vote helpful things and accept an answer (even if you have to write it yourself) so that SO can properly archive the question.